# How to have logo change positioning at certain breakpoints

Tags: html, css

I have the following header on my page:

[image: Desktop screenshot]

When I shrink the window, the email disappears pretty quickly for anything smaller than desktop size.

What can I do in CSS to influence the breakpoints, and positioning of the elements on certain breakpoints?

Also, I'd like the phone number and email address to be centered and stacked on top of each other at mobile size, at the top there. At the moment, the email is missing, and the phone number stays to the left:

[image: Mobile screenshot]

Comment: can I see your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query in your css to change the style of your elements at certain breakpoints.

Here is an example of how you can change the style of your layout:

```css
<style>

/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, the background color is olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
    color: white;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS breakpoints are handled through media queries. There are usually at a minimum three breakpoints used, and more depending on targeted devices at 320px and below, 720px and below, and 720px and above. The following media query will target a screen pixel range from 320px to 720px. The class .style1 at any other screen size will be 60px wide. You could add more media queries to control elements styling at different screen sizes.

```css
.col{
    color:#fff;
    float:left;
    margin:2%;
 width: 46%;
}
.one{
  background-color: #e95b33;
}

.two{
  background-color: #40b7d7;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
  .col{
   float: none;
   margin:0;
   width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col one">
   <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col two">
   <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. </p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but im confused as to what else i add into the css. Ive never messed with media queries before. Do i need to include a class in the html to target these elements?

Comment: Yep! So you would replace /*Styles */ with your normal class/id CSS. I'll edit the answer with an example.

Comment: No the media query just asks the screen which size it is over and over. If screen size matches the query, it overrides any CSS above it with the new styles that are inside the query.

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend watching some videos and doing some reading on CSS, HTML, and media queries. Youtube, codecademy.com, and w3 are all great resources :)